# MongoDB - Distinct performance - not as expected

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing, distinct

I have read this "bug" report already - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4095

However, it doesn't quite explain why "distinct" is not scanning only the top of the B-tree index, which IS only 4 entries. Here's what I do:

```
run Distinct

Result
"n" : 535216,
            "nscanned" : 535216,
            "nscannedObjects" : 0,
            "timems" : 1871,
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor path_1"

db.logs.dropIndex("path_1")

run Distinct

Result
            "n" : 535216,
            "nscanned" : 535216,
            "nscannedObjects" : 535216,
            "timems" : 1426,
            "cursor" : "BasicCursor"
```

**Could someone please try to give an exact explanation of why this happens?** 
The explanation with memory overhead doesn't make me happy really. If you have a B-Tree index with 4 elements on the top level, why would that be a problem?
Constructive feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: also did you run the command just once or a couple of times?

Comment: 2.2, @AsyaKamsky. I checked this a number of times.

Comment: this is the ticket that if fixed would speed up your query. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2094  vote it up please.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, thank you! I shall register and contribute!